# location header not working, any ideas?

Tags: redirect, header, location

as you can see below i have a login page which will return to the index depending on the outcome. when i come to this page it just does nothing. the session's ect register and login but i have to manually re enter the page my self?

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connect_db.php");

$tbl_name="users"; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header('location: index.php?login=yes');
    }
    else {
        header('location: index.php?login=no');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you also add the contents of your `connect_db.php` file?

According to manual, "header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called." Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php ...


If possible, please attach the contents of your `php.ini`.

Comment: ive realised when i add the connect_db.php file content directly to this code it works but when i use 'include' funtion it does not. any ideas

Comment: `<?php
$dbservername = "xxx";
$dbusername = "xxx";
$dbpassword = "xxx";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$db  = mysql_select_db("xxx", $conn);
if (!$conn) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
?> `

Comment: Maybe it can't connect to the MySQL server, and so, in result, it outputs some data through `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` Anyway, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

> ive realised when i add the connect_db.php file content directly to
>   this code it works but when i use 'include' funtion it does not. any
>   ideas

If that's so, try output buffering.

Now your code should look like this:

```
<?php
// Output buffering
ob_start();
include("connect_db.php");
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
echo $buffer;
// End OB

session_start();

$tbl_name="users"; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header('location: index.php?login=yes');
    }
    else {
        header('location: index.php?login=no');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks still no luck also not displaying echo $buffer; im really confused

Comment: ive tried using     window.location.href = '/index.php?login=yes' which works but not if the count is not == 1